# using regular expression substitution command to insert leading zeros in front of numbers less than 10 in a string of filenames

Tags: python, regex, expression, regex-group

I am having trouble figuring out how to make this work with substitution command, which is what I have been instructed to do. I am using this text as a variable:

```
text = 'file1, file2, file10, file20'
```

I want to search the text and substitute in a zero in front of any numbers less than 10. I thought I could do and if statement depending on whether or not re.match or findall would find only one digit after the text, but I can't seem to execute. Here is my starting code where I am trying to extract the string and digits into groups, and only extract the those file names with only one digit:

```
import re
text = 'file1, file2, file10, file20'
mtch = re.findall('^([a-z]+)(\d{1})$',text)
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
re.sub('[a-zA-Z]\d,', lambda x: x.group(0)[0] + '0' + x.group(0)[1:], s)
```

Comment: the search pattern that I used `'[a-zA-Z]\d,'` returns a string of *len()=3*, and the `re.sub()` method allows you to use this string by calling a function as the second argument, which makes it pretty easy to build complex replacemen ts using the values from the matched string. You should [refer here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more details and examples...

Comment: its this part i'm not totally clear on: x.group(0)[0] + '0' + x.group(0)[1:]

Comment: for each match it finds one group that can be accessed using `group(0)`, containing three characters `'e1,'`, `'e2,'`, then I use these characters by slicing `[0]-->'e'` and `[1:]-->'1,' or '2,'` to rebuild the string to replace the original...

Comment: got it! great solution

Comment: so wait, actually, how is it that zeros only get added to the single digit numbers? sorry i am new with python

Comment: the trick is that `[a-zA-Z]\d,` recognized one letter, one digit and the comma. Where you have two digits the match does not occur...

Comment: last question - what does the comma do in the expression?

Comment: It is just one character... in order to get `e0,` and not `e0 ` (with space), for example... it is ok to ask... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.sub` with `str.zfill`:

```
>>> text = 'file1, file2, file10, file20'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda m : m.group(1).zfill(2), text)
'file01, file02, file10, file20'
#or
>>> re.sub(r'([a-z]+)(\d+)', lambda m : m.group(1)+m.group(2).zfill(2), text)
'file01, file02, file10, file20'
```

Comment: thanks! but what i have other filenames in my string, like file100? i only want one leading zero

Answer (score 1):

Anchors anchor to the beginning and end of strings (or lines, in multi-line mode). What you're looking for are *word boundaries*. And of course, you don't need the `{1}` quantifier.

```
\b([a-z]+)(\d)\b
```

(Not sure how you plan to use your captures, so I'll leave those alone.)

Comment: when i tried this and tried to print mtch, it gave me a blank list:

Answer (score 0):

You have the start and end anchors applied, so the pattern cannot be fully matched.

Try something like this

```
text = "file1, file2, file3, file4, file10, file20, file100"
print re.sub("(?<=[a-z])\d(?!\d),?", "0\g<0>", text)
```

will result in

```
file01, file02, file03, file04, file10, file20, file100
```

This should work if you have a list like above or a single element name.

**Explanation**

`(?<=[a-z])` - Checks that the previous characters are letters using look behind

`\d` - matches a single digit

`(?!\d)` - Checks that there are no more digits using lookahead

`,?` - allows for an optional comma in the list

`0\g<0>` - The pattern matches a single digit, so it trivial to add a zero. The `\g<0>` is the matched group.